# Why sometimes this code works and sometimes it doesn't?

Tags: database, vba, macros, range

I got this macro that makes visual aids for labeling circuits from my electrical warehouse, and I want to identify them, but sometimes it works (only in the two first labels, and then, it lacks information in some cells, this is the code:

```
Public Sub VisualAids()
Dim DB_Range, StartVisuals As range
Dim Origen As range
Set DB_Range = Worksheets("DBCircuits").range("B2:K573")
Set Origen = Worksheets("visuales").range("C2")
Dim i, j, TotalLabels, LabelsCounter As Integer
Dim Labels As Integer
Dim CircuitName, Location, Color1, Color2, DailyReq, StdPack As String
TotalLabels = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("DBCircuits").range("K2:K573"))

For i = 1 To TotalLabels
CircuitName = DB_Range.Cells(i, 1)
Location = DB_Range.Cells(i, 8)
Color1 = DB_Range.Cells(i, 6)
Color2 = DB_Range.Cells(i, 7)
DailyReq = DB_Range.Cells(i, 3)
StdPack = DB_Range.Cells(i, 4)
Labels = DB_Range.Cells(i, 10)

For j = 1 To Labels
Origen.Offset(0, 1) = CircuitName
Origen.Offset(1, 1) = Location
Origen.Offset(3, 1) = DailyReq
Origen.Offset(4, 1) = StdPack

Select Case Color1
Case "0"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Case "1"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 102, 51)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 102, 51)
Case "2"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Case "3"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
Case "4"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Case "5"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Case "6"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Case "7"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Case "8"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
Case "9"
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Case Else
Origen.Offset(2, 3).Value = "-"
Origen.Offset(2, 5).Value = "-"
End Select

Select Case Color2
Case "0"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Case "1"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 102, 51)
Case "2"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Case "3"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
Case "4"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Case "5"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Case "6"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Case "7"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
Case "8"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
Case "9"
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Case Else
Origen.Offset(2, 4).Value = "-"
End Select
LabelsCounter = LabelsCounter + 1

If LabelsCounter Mod 2 = 0 Then
Origen.Offset(6, 1) = "Back visual"
'the next one would be down-left
Set Origen = Origen.Offset(11, -9)
Else
Origen.Offset(6, 1) = "Front visual"
'the next one would be right
Set Origen = Origen.Offset(0, 9)
End If

Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

with this i pretend to fill this cells (visuals worksheet) [image: Image1]

and the DB_Range is the following (DBCircuits worksheet): [image: image2]

the point is that sometimes the CircuitName is not added to the visuals, and also the position, can you help me please? I still working to find the problem

Comment: Try to add `.Value` after these: `Origen.Offset(0, 1)` so it is `Origen.Offset(0, 1).Value =`

Comment: If you wish to declare several `Range` variables in one row then you will have to write `Dim DB_Range as Range, StartVisuals As Range`. Your line `Dim DB_Range, StartVisuals As Range` is equivalent to `Dim DB_Range as Variant, StartVisuals As Range` and this line of yours `Dim CircuitName, Location, Color1, Color2, DailyReq, StdPack As String` is to VBA the same as `Dim CircuitName as Variant, Location as Variant, Color1 as Variant, Color2 as Variant, DailyReq as Variant, StdPack As String`. Changing that might solve some problems.

Comment: thank you @ib11 , it was also the problem, but the real issue was that I wanted to put a value in a merged cells, I missed this code (this is one example) `Origen.Offset(0, 1).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value = CircuitName` , so I add this code to some statements, and also your suggestion, thank you very much.
by the way @Ralph, I didn't want to do so because of memory usage, but at the end, it wasn't the issue, thanks anyway, I really appreciate your help

Comment: OK, @JoeJoe I made this into an answer now so that you have something to accept. Also note, that the `.Value` does work on merged cells, so you don't have to have `MergeArea` (at leasts per my tests).

Comment: @JoeJoe Thanks for accepting. Don't forget the upvote either (you know... just protocol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `.Value` after these lines: `Origen.Offset(0, 1)` so it is `Origen.Offset(0, 1).Value =`

So you would have:

```
Origen.Offset(0, 1).Value = CircuitName
Origen.Offset(1, 1).Value = Location
Origen.Offset(3, 1).Value = DailyReq
Origen.Offset(4, 1).Value = StdPack
```

(This works for both single or merged cells, which you have.)